# How can I save filter and variable statuses in Workshop?

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-workshop

I have a Workshop module that I use to analyze data in. Sometimes I want to save the Workshop as I left it after configuring filters so that I can share it with others and pick back up with my analyses later on. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this via state saving. You start by promoting variables, which makes them savable.
[image: Promote variable]
Then click on the settings icon. From there you can switch on “State Saving”
[image: turn on state saving]
Now whenever you would like to save the state of your workshop, you will be able to do so by selecting `Saved module states` from the header of your module and then selecting `Save as new module state`.
[image: Save as module state]
For more context on the feature, check out the documentation [here](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/workshop/state-saving/).